# Implementing intereaved products and sums in Python without loop overhead

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement in python logically nested sums and partial products in order to build a function. The idea is to do so without explicit loops. The desired output is a list (indexed by t for a given matrix J)

The formula is:

[image: formula]

Short verbal description of the formula: For each t, there are 3 indices i,j,k in the range 0-(N-1). The indices i,j build a matrix (or a 2d array), each of whose elements is a product of some (J,t)-dependent function (doesn't matter what) over the index k excluding the particular value of i,j. The function is just numpy.sum over the flattened matrix/array.

Now, the code below works as expected:

```
import numpy as np 
t_output = np.arange(0,10,100)
jmat = np.random.random(N**2).reshape(N,N)

def corr_mat(i,j,t,params):
  return np.prod(np.cos(\
    2.0 * t * np.delete(jmat[:,i] + jmat[:,j],(i,j)))) + \
      np.prod(np.cos(\
        2.0 * t * np.delete(jmat[:,i] - jmat[:,j],(i,j))))

def corr_time(t, jmat):
   return np.array([corr_mat(i,j,t,jmat) for i in xrange(N)\
     for j in xrange(N)]).reshape(N,N)

result = np.array([np.sum(corr_time(t,jmat)) for t in t_output])
```

but the nested for loops in the "corr_time" function slows the execution down immensely. I tried this

```
import numpy as np 
t_output = np.arange(0,10,100)
jmat = np.random.random(N**2).reshape(N,N)

def corr_mat(i,j,t,params):
  return np.prod(np.cos(\
    2.0 * t * np.delete(jmat[:,i] + jmat[:,j],(i,j)))) + \
      np.prod(np.cos(\
        2.0 * t * np.delete(jmat[:,i] - jmat[:,j],(i,j))))

i,j = np.meshgrid(range(0,N), range(0,N))

result = np.array([np.sum(corr_mat(i,j,t,params)) for t in t_output])
```

but the meshgrid is not being comprehended correctly by the functions. Can anyone please suggest what I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you describe as working as expected seems to return `array([2*N**2])` for me.  Is that right?

Comment: `t_output = np.arange(0,100,10)` would be a more reasonable `t_output` value.

Comment: You need to write `corr_mat` in such a way that it works with vector values for `i` and `j`.  I'd also try to avoid using `np.delete`, especially repeatedly.  It's a slow operation.

Comment: @DSM: It should return (in the variable "result") an array of size "t_output"

Comment: @hpaulj: well the index t need not stride across the same range as the other indices. In principle it could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precalculating the `jmat` sum/difference arrays makes a big (45x) difference in performance.

```
def precalc(jmat):
  JM1 = np.zeros((N,N,N))
  JM2 = np.zeros((N,N,N))
  for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
      for k in range(N):
        #JJ[i,j,k]=jmat[k,i]+jmat[k,j]
        if k!=i and k!=j:
          JM1[i,j,k]=jmat[k,i]+jmat[k,j]
          JM2[i,j,k]=jmat[k,i]-jmat[k,j]
  return JM1, JM2

def corr_time1(t, JM1, JM2):
    return np.prod(np.cos(2*JM1*t),axis=-1)+np.prod(np.cos(2*JM2*t),axis=-1)

JM1, JM2 = precalc(jmat)
result = np.array([np.sum(corr_time1(t,JM1,JM2)) for t in t_output])
```

There is room for further improvement.  I took a brute force approach to `precalc` since I wasn't finding a more vectorized approach.  There probably still is such a solution.  Still only doing the j,i,k iteration only once helps substantially.

We can vectorize the last step by doing the `np.prod` on a larger dimensional array, one that used the whole `t_output`:

```
def corr_time2(t, JM1, JM2):
    return np.prod(np.cos(2*JM1[None,...]*t[:,None,None,None]),axis=-1) +\
       np.prod(np.cos(2*JM2[None,...]*t[:,None,None,None]),axis=-1)
result = np.sum(corr_time2(t_output, JM1, JM2),axis=(1,2))
```

In this test case, the time savings are modest, only 20%.  I think that's because `t_output` has only 10 elements.  `np.arange(0,100,10)`.  And in this last version `precalc` is the biggest time consumer.

---

Fast `precalc` with a 28x speedup

```
def precalc1(jmat):
  # calc all the 'outer' sums/diffs, and zero the k=i,j terms
  ii = np.arange(jmat.shape[0])
  JM1 = jmat[:,:,None] + jmat[:,None,:]
  JM2 = jmat[:,:,None] - jmat[:,None,:]
  JM1[ii,ii,:] = 0
  JM2[ii,ii,:] = 0
  JM1[ii,:,ii] = 0
  JM2[ii,:,ii] = 0
  JM1 = JM1.transpose([1,2,0])
  JM2 = JM2.transpose([1,2,0])
  return JM1, JM2
```

Comment: Thanks a million. That's working fine! What is the significance of "None" in the array slices?

Comment: `None` is the same as `np.newaxis`.  It adds a new dimension to the array.  With broadcasting `x[:,None]*y[None,:]` equals `z_ij=x_i*y_j`(for all i,j)